# PostgreSQL real type losing integer precision when printed with PHP sprintf

Tags: php, postgresql, precision

I have copied [this table from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_use_statistics_by_country) into a PostgreSQL database. The column `Cultivated land (km2)` became a column of type `real`. Then I use the PHP command

```
echo rtrim(rtrim(sprintf('%.10F',$v),'0'),'.');
```

to display the numbers (`$v`) in a table (both integers and float), but some values lose precision. For instance, the value from United States, 1669302, becomes 1669300, what is strange, since [I expected 10 decimal digits of precision](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). I thought I have lost the precision when saving into a `real` column, but converting the column to `double precision` makes the difference (02) appear again, so it was there somewhere.

I don't think I need double precision, so how can I display the real value correctly? Keep in mind that some columns have decimal places, while some others are `bigint`, and they also should be displayed correctly.

Comment: what is value of `Cultivated land ` that saved in database

Comment: @Rafiq without formatting, it shows as 1.6693e+06. But I know the missing 02 (1669302 - 1669300) is still there, because it shows up again if I run `alter table "LandUseWP" alter column "cultKm2" type double precision;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to originate from the way PHP returns results. The values are not returned as the corresponding data type, but rather [formatted as a string using PostgreSQL default formatting](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-result.php#refsect1-function.pg-fetch-result-returnvalues). This formatting, is different for `real` and `double precision` types hence you are seeing different results when you convert the column types of your table. The reason you are seeing this specific result is that [PostgreSQL guarantees 6 decimal places for `real` types and 15 decimal places for `double precision`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC).

#### Setting `extra_float_digits`

The manual [states](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT)

> Note: The `extra_float_digits` setting controls the number of extra significant digits included when a floating point value is converted to text for output. With the default value of `0`, the output is the same on every platform supported by PostgreSQL. Increasing it will produce output that more accurately represents the stored value, but may be unportable.

Therefore, a simple solution to your problem is to increase `extra_float_digits` before issuing your `SELECT`-query:

```
pg_query($connection, "set extra_float_digits = 3");
```

Alternatively, you can also specify this change when connecting to your database by adding `options` to your [connection string](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php#refsect1-function.pg-connect-parameters) as follows:

```
$connection = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test user=php password=pass connect_timeout=5 options='-c extra_float_digits=3'");
```

Another option would be to [set this flag](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-EXTRA-FLOAT-DIGITS) in the `postgresql.conf` configuration file of the PostgreSQL server if you have access to the server and want to change the option globally.

#### Casting the values

A different solution would be to have PostgreSQL return a different string to the PHP backend. This can be achieved by casting your columns to types with different default formatting which avoids cutting off some of the digits. In your case you could either cast to `integer` or `double precision`, i.e. instead of using

```
select cultivated_land from table
```

you could use

```
select cultivated_land::integer from table
```

or

```
select cultivated_land::double precision from table
```

#### Changing data types

Looking at the data you specified, I noticed that all numerical values except those columns specifying percentages contain integers, hence the usage of the `integer` data type is more suitable in this case. It can fit all the integer values of this table (the maximum being 149,000,000, therefore `bigint` is not required), requires the same storage size as `real` (4 bytes) and implies the  default formatting of integers that you are looking for.

#### Update: Background on PostgreSQL-PHP interface and floating point representation

As mentioned above the way the PostgreSQL-PHP interface works is that all values sent from PostgreSQL to PHP are formatted as a string in some type-dependent way. Neither any of the `pg_fetch_*` functions nor `pg_copy_to` will provide raw values and *all of these functions convert the values to strings in the same manner*. As far as I am aware the current PHP interface will not provide you with anything different from a string (which, in my opinion, is not the best interface design).

The reason `18.22` is returned as `18.2199993` can be found in how PostgreSQL converts `float4` to strings. You can [check the code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/adt/float.c#L382) of how PostgreSQL is internally using `float4out` and find this relevant line that does the string-conversion:

```
snprintf(ascii, MAXFLOATWIDTH + 1, "%.*g", ndig, num);
```

`num` is the `float4`-number to be printed as a string. Note however that C will [promote the `float`-variable to a `double`-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097564/why-does-printf-promote-a-float-to-a-double) when calling `snprintf`. This conversion to double precision results in the value `18.219999313354492` which is why you end up seeing `18.2199993` (you can check this [here](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) and will also find some details on floating point number representation on this site).

The takeaway message is that all your `float4` values will be converted using this function and the only parameter you can influence is `ndig` by varying `extra_float_digits`, however no single value for this variable will suffice all your needs in representing the values as you want them. So as long as you keep using `float4` as your data type and use the current PHP-interface to obtain the data you will run into these problems.

I therefore still recommend choosing different data types for your columns. If you think you have a requirement for decimal numbers you might want to investigate [`decimal` data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) where you can specify precision and scale as required for your application. If you would like to stick with floating point numbers I suggest rounding the values in PHP before displaying them to the user.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Set extra_float_digits will turn fields like 18.22 into 18.2199993 (as seen in pgAdmin), I don't like that. Casting the values will require rewriting all the dynamic queries on the fly (now they're just `select * from $tab`). Changing data types is still an option, maybe I'll turn all float4 into float8 (some columns only contain integers right now, but in the future I may find out that Tokelau has 0.1 km2 of cultivated land. And I don't want to trouble the user with the distinction between int and bigint). Anyway, there may be some other, more direct, solution.

Comment: @Rodrigo I updated the answer to provide some detail as to why this happens.

Comment: Great! I think the best solution in my case now is to use `decimal`/`numeric` type. Since any table will not have much more than 300 lines, the space occupied is not a big issue. Thank you very much!