# Why is clang 3.8 warning on use of float with %f printf format specifier?

Tags: c, clang, compiler-warnings

This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  float value = 10.10f;
  printf("%f\n",value);
}
```

compiled with the -Weverything option using clang 3.8 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 gives:

```
clang -Weverything w-double-precision.c 
w-double-precision.c:5:17: warning: implicit conversion increases floating-point precision: 'float' to 'double' [-Wdouble-promotion]
  printf("%f\n",value);
  ~~~~~~        ^~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: because in vararg functions, [floats are always promoted to double](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28097564/995714)

Comment: OK, thanks! You should make that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `printf()` function is a **variadic**, or **vararg**, function; one that accepts a variable number of arguments. 
The way the printf() function is defined in [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) is as follows:

> ```
> int printf( const char *format, ... );
> ```

The `...` indicates that this function can accept a variable number of arguments.

In a *variadic* function, if a variable of type `float` is passed to it, it will automatically convert it to a `double` value; an *implicit* conversion from type `float` to type `double` is done.

In your code, you pass a floating point-type variable `value` to `printf()`, as an additional argument in addition to the `"%f\n"` parameter. Hence, since `printf()` is a **vararg** function, it convert `value` to type `double` before passing it as an argument. Depending on how high you have kept your compiler's warnings, it is giving you that warning.

Hope this helps!