# Printing a float in asm

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I have the following program to print a float in asm with the help of C's `printf`:

```
.section .rodata
format: .ascii "Your number is: %f\n\0"
.section .text
.globl main
main:
    lea format(%rip), %rdi
    mov $0b1000000001011001100110011001101, %xmm0 # the number 2.7
    mov $0, %eax
    add $-8, %rsp
    call printf@plt
    add $8, %rsp
    mov $0, %eax
    ret
```

However, I get an error when assembling it with:

> int_c.s:7: Error: unsupported instruction `mov'

Are you not allowed to add immediates into the `xmm` registers, or what seems to be the issue with the above program?

---

Update: I got it to compile but then I think my issue is that the `movq` accepts 8 byte but I'm looking to get a 4-byte float into the fp register:

```
mov $2.7, %eax # using '2.7' to be more readable
movq %eax, %xmm0
```

And after stepping through the instructions it looks correct before calling `printf`:

```
>>> p $xmm0
$2 = {
  v4_float = {[0] = 2.70000005, [1] = 0, [2] = 0, [3] = 0},
  v2_double = {[0] = 5.3194953090036137e-315, [1] = 0},
...
}
```

Comment: Indeed that is the problem. Consult an instruction set reference when in doubt.

Comment: @Jester sure, `movq` works, though it still seems there's an issue when adding that in that the number shows `0`.

Comment: @Jester updated the question.

Comment: `printf` expects a `double` so it's going to be looking at the low 64 bits (`v2_double` to gdb) which is not the value you want.

Comment: @NateEldredge I see. Why does it expect a double instead of a float if I pass it the `%f` format?

Comment: Does `mov $2.7, %rax; mov %rax, %xmm0` work?

Comment: @prl not using gas, but I just type that in so it's easier to show (the actual value in the text is that binary at the top).

Comment: @carl.hiass https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097564/why-does-printf-promote-a-float-to-a-double and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf?rq=1

Comment: Anyway, the most typical way to get a floating point constant into a register is to load from memory.

Comment: Oh, and since you are now passing 1 floating point argument in xmm registers, you need your `mov $0, %eax` to now be `mov $1, %eax`.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks. What does `eax` represent in the print call? And is there a good reference from a register/low-level how the printf function is called/works?

Comment: [Where is the x86-64 System V ABI documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18133812) documents the calling convention.  ISO C specifies how printf conversions work (and C "default argument promotions" for the variadic args).  @Nate: There's an asm-specific [How to print a single-precision float with printf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37082784) which explains the need to `cvtss2sd`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of your program, writing the value to memory and then using [`cvtss2sd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtss2sd) to convert your float to a double:

```
format: .ascii "Your number is: %f\n\0"
.section .text
.globl main
main:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    lea format(%rip), %rdi

    # move float to memory and upgrade to 8 bytes
    movl $0b1000000001011001100110011001101, -4(%rbp)
    cvtss2sd -4(%rbp), %xmm0

    mov $1, %eax
    call printf@plt
    mov $0, %eax
    mov %rbp, %rsp
    pop %rbp
    ret
```

`rax` will be the number of float arguments in `printf`. See: [Why is %eax zeroed before a call to printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212665/why-is-eax-zeroed-before-a-call-to-printf/6212755#6212755).

Comment: Normally you'd want `format` in `.section .rodata`.  The default section at the top of the file is `.text`, so that's where you put it.  Also, the normal way to 0-terminate is with `.asciiz`, rather than `.ascii` with an explicit `\0`

Comment: Also, `cvtss2sd` works with registers too so you don't have to go through memory.

Comment: Other than that, yeah this is fine for un-optimized code.  No real need to set up RBP as a frame pointer, and you could `pushq $0b1000000001011001100110011001101` to align the stack and store the float constant.  (Still just read the low 4 bytes of it, ignoring the sign-extended high half.)

Comment: @Jester how could I do the above with a register? I tried moving from `rax` to `xmm0` but that was giving me `0` when I tried.

Comment: `movl $0b1000000001011001100110011001101, %eax; movd %eax, %xmm0; cvtss2sd %xmm0, %xmm0`

Comment: @Jester: that would take an extra instruction, for `mov $0b1000000001011001100110011001101, %eax` / `movd %eax, %xmm0` / `cvtss2sd %xmm0, %xmm0`.  That's why compilers normally load float constants from memory (in .rodata, same place they'd put format strings and so on), instead of using immediates at all.