# Segmentation fault in x86 while computing floating point sequence

Tags: x86, nasm

Assembly program to compute sum of given sequence: 1+(1/1!)+(1/2!)+...+(1/10!)
using floating point registers.
Why do I get a segmentation fault(Core dumped) error in the following program?

```
global  main
main:
    mov eax,2
    mov ebx, 2
    mov edx, 2
.fact:
    fld dword [ecx]
    fmul dword [ebx]
    fstp dword [ecx]
    fld dword [ebx]
    fadd dword [one]
    fstp dword [ebx]
    fld dword [ebx]
    fld dword [eax]
    fcomi st0,st1
    ja .fact
.sum:
    fld dword [one]
    fdiv dword [ecx]
    fadd dword [edx]
    fstp dword [edx]
    fld dword [ten]    
    fld dword [eax]
    fcomi st0,st1
    ja .exit
    fadd dword [one]
    mov ebx,2
    jmp .fact
.exit:
    push edx
    push    dword msg       
    call    printf  
    add     sp, 8
```

Comment: Those brackets indicate loads from/stores to memory. 2 is a pretty dangerous pointer.

Comment: Can you step through the code and highlight what instruction the fault occurs on?

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea, but I can see a number of issues with this code that will prevent it from working as intended:

### You need to allocate memory

As it was already mentioned in the comments, **the brackets in these floating-point instructions indicate loads/stores to memory.**  For example, the statement `fld dword [ecx]` does not load the contents of `ecx` into `st0`.  It loads *the 32-bit floating point value at address* `ecx` into `st0`.  Right now, in several cases, you're trying to read/write from address `2`.

So for all of those loads and stores to work, you'll need to allocate variables on your stack.  You use four of them (`eax`, `ecx`, `edx`, and `ebx`), and each is four bytes in size, so you can keep the register usage the way it currently is if you start your routine with something like:

```
sub esp, 0x10
lea eax, [esp]
lea ecx, [esp+4]
lea edx, [esp+8]
lea ebx, [esp+0xC]
```

If you're unfamiliar with `lea`, it loads an *address* without reading from memory.  **`lea` is the only<sup>1</sup> x86 instruction where the brackets don't imply a memory access**.  So for example, the second line is functionally equivalent to `mov eax, esp`.

Finally, remember to put the stack pointer back where it was before you leave the routine (`add esp, 0x10`).

### You're not setting floating-point constants correctly

As mentioned in the previous section, instructions like `mov ebx, 2` will not do what you want, because we want `ebx` to point to some address in memory where we can store floats.

But even if you wrote `mov dword [ebx], 2` to store `2` to *address* `ebx`, this would still be wrong, because in this routine, we treat `[ebx]` as a float, whereas the `2` you're storing to that location is *the integer representation of 2.*

The `fild` instruction loads an integer from memory, converts it to a floating-point value, and stores it at the top of the FPU stack.  For example, the following instructions would convert an integer to a float:

```
mov dword [ebx], 2  ; Now [ebx] contains 2
fild dword [ebx]    ; Now st0 contains 2.0
fstp dword [ebx]    ; Now [ebx] contains 2.0
```

### You're overflowing the FPU stack

Every time you use `fld` you push a value onto the FPU stack.  Every `fstp` pops a value off the FPU stack.  (That's what the 'p' means in `fstp`)  The way you're using `fadd`, `fmul`, and `fdiv` just replace the value which is currently at the top of the FPU stack (a.k.a. `st0`).  That's all fine, but `fcomi` doesn't pop anything off the FPU stack.  So every time you go through the loop and do two `fld`s followed by a `fcomi`, you're adding two values to the stack and leaving them there.

The FPU stack can only store 8 values (`st0` through `st7`).  So if all eight are filled and you try to push another value onto the FPU stack (e.g. with `fld`), then you'll get a *FPU stack-overflow exception* and the load will fail.

There is another compare instruction, `fcomip`, but it only pops *one* value off the FPU stack.  To pop the other, you can use `fstp st0`.  This instruction basically means "Store `st0` to `st0`, then pop the top value off the FPU stack."

### `printf` doesn't support floats

[When passing a `float` to a variadic function, it is automatically promoted to a `double`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14227035/1354557)  As `printf` is a variadic function, the `%f` specifier (then of course) also expects a `double`.  So, at the end of your function, you want to print the contents of `[edx]` (not `edx`!) as a double.  Since `printf` expects a double (which is 64 bits wide), something like `push dword [edx]` won't cut it.

When you load values onto the FPU stack, they're stored with the highest precision possible.  When you store them to memory (via `fstp`) you get to specify the precision (and thus the format and width).  When you say `fstp dword [address]`, you're specifying `dword` width, i.e. a 32-bit float.  If you want a `double`, you just specify `qword`.

We can store values directly onto the stack.  So try something like:

```
sub esp, 8       ; Make space for the 64-bit double we're about to store
fld dword [edx]  ; Load the 32-bit float we want to print
fstp qword [esp] ; Store the 64-bit double to the space we just allocated
```

Remember that after the `printf`, you'll need to readjust your stack pointer (not just by 8 bytes anymore!).  Also, note that the stack pointer in any 32-bit mode is **`esp`**, not **`sp`**.

### You need to initialize your product

The fourth instruction you have up there is `fld dword [ecx]`.  We haven't initialized `ecx` yet in this routine.  Since you are using `[ecx]` to store the product for your factorial, you'll want this to be set to `1.0` before *each time* you begin the `.fact` loop.

### The condition on your factorial loop is off by one

It looks like you're making an optimization by starting your main loop counter (`[eax]`) with `2` and initializing your sum with `2 = 1/0! + 1/1!`.  And before you run through the `.fact` loop, you initialize `[ebx]` to `2`, presumably another optimization to avoid multiplying by 1.  In pseudocode, your algorithm looks like this:

```
// B is initialized to 2
.fact:
    C = C * B
    B = B + 1
    if A > B: goto .fact
```

So essentially (if `C` starts at 1), `C` is the product of all integers from `2` to `A-1`, always including `2` no matter what.

This isn't exactly what you want.  Remember that you want to include `1/10!` in the sum, which, as written above, would require executing `.fact` with `A=11`.  Also, consider the result of `C` in this algorithm for different values of `A`:

```
A:  2  3  4  5   6   ...
C:  2  2  6  24  120 ...
```

So referencing the above chart, according to the rest of your algorithm, the final sum will be `2 + 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/6 + 1/24 + 1/120 ...`.  This will be off by `1/2`.

You can fix both of these issues by changing one line.

### Extra stuff

- You need to exit your program somehow or you'll just keep executing instructions beyond the boundaries of the program until you segfault
- There are special instructions for loading common values onto the FPU stack.  Two of them could be useful to you:  `fldz` loads `+0.0` and `fld1` loads `1.0`
- Any time you want an answer to the question *"Why did my program segfault?"* you should run the program in a debugger.  It will show you the exact instruction where the segfault occurred and allow you to examine the state of the program (registers, contents of memory, etc).  The payoff of learning a few quick commands in the debugger is well worth it :)

<sup>1</sup> *It's the only one you likely need to care about.  To be pedantic, the `nop` instruction can also take an address argument, but as you would expect, it does not actually access the memory because it's a **no-op**.*

Comment: Great answer, except I wouldn't encourage a beginner to waste 4 registers on pointers that way.  Presumably the OP wants to convert between integer values in integer registers and FP values in FP registers.  (In which case, SSE2 makes it a lot easier: [`cvtsi2sd xmm0, eax`, for example](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTSI2SD.html).)  Also, I usually link the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) in answers for beginners, because most people don't know that it's actually useful.